# SQL - Sample and Filter by the grouping variable

Tags: sql, filter, group-by

I have a table that looks like the following

```
V1 |  Group  |  time    
----------------------
a  |     g1  |   1      
b  |     g1  |   2      
c  |     g1  |   3      
d  |     g2  |   1      
e  |     g2  |   2      
f  |     g2  |   3      
g  |     g3  |   5
h  |     g3  |   6
i  |     g3  |   7
```

I wish to filter only a sample `Group`s, but take all of the associated examples with the filtered groups. For example, assuming that the desired sample size is `2 groups`, and `(g1,g3)` were sampled, the desired table will be

```
V1 |  Group  |  time    
----------------------
a  |     g1  |   1      
b  |     g1  |   2      
c  |     g1  |   3 
g  |     g3  |   5
h  |     g3  |   6
i  |     g3  |   7
```

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL 8, MySQL 5.x, SQL Server, etc? Each has different options to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

Note that I renamed `group` to `g` because it is usually a reserved SQL Keyword and that you may have to use another rand function depending on your DB (I assume SQL Server here).

```
drop table if exists #have;

CREATE TABLE #have 
(
  V1    VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
, g     VARCHAR(3)       
, time  INT
);


insert into #have
values
  ('a', 'g1', 1)
, ('b', 'g1', 2)
, ('c', 'g1', 3)
, ('d', 'g2', 1)
, ('e', 'g2', 2)
, ('f', 'g2', 3)
, ('g', 'g3', 5)
, ('h', 'g3', 6)
, ('i', 'g3', 7)
;

select a.*
from #have a join
(
select top 2 g
from #have
group by g
order by newid()
) b
on a.g = b.g;
```

Comment: @MatBailie, yes, edited a few seconds ago to clarify

Answer (score 3):

A simple query like this would give you the results you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Group IN('g1','g3');
```

Alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Group = 'g1' OR Group = 'g3';
```

Note `GROUP` is a reserved word in most RDBMSs so you probably need to escape them. In MySQL/MariaDB you can use backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Group` IN('g1','g3');
```

If ANSI SQL mode is enabled you can use double quotes :

```
SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE "Group" IN('g1','g3');
```

In T-SQL you can use brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [Group] IN('g1','g3');
```

If you want a randomized sample of two groups, and use `SQL Server` you should go with [PeterClemmensens excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74773144/1363190)

With a few changes in syntax his solution works well also for MySQL/MariaDB 5.5 and above:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `table` a JOIN (
     SELECT `Group`
     FROM `table`
     GROUP BY `Group`
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 2
) b
ON a.`Group` = b.`Group`;
```